# Error deploying hybrid app in vs2013

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I have been building Cordova hybrid apps using visual studio professional 2013 with CTP2.0 and everything was working fine. Then Visual Studio warned me that I should upgrade to update 4.0 and CTP 3.0. After that upgrade I was no longer able to deploy my app. It builds OK but the deploy fails. I tried to reinstall VS2013 and even reset my laptop to factory settings.

When deploying I receive the following message in the output window:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BlankCordovaApp1, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>C:\Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(95,5): warning : The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling.
1> GeneratedJavascript= 1> C:\Users\Abel Silva\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp
1>call "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat
1> Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.33 (ia32) and npm.
1> ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\TCFZDSVO.K3U\packages\vs-mda
2>------ Deploy started: Project: BlankCordovaApp1, Configuration: Debug Android ------
2>Starting launch process C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe ""C:\Users\Abel Silva\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\emulator.js"" --platform android --path "C:\Users\Abel Silva\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\bld\Debug" --deployTarget "emulator" --language pt-PT --configuration debug
2>C:\Users\Abel:1
2>function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ****************
2>                                                             ^
2>SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
2>
2>at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
2>at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2>at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2>at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2>at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
2>at startup (node.js:119:16)
2>at node.js:906:3
2>C:\Users\Abel:1
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems because of space in user name (Abel Silva), VS is adding double double quotes while calling emulator.js for deploying the app. Try with user name without space. **""**C:\Users\Abel Silva\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\emulator.js**""**

Comment: Abel Silva it's my windows username. Can I change it? If I do change it will the system change the path?

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks @Abhishek.